# I need help understanding what r-th and s-th rows are.

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

> Let E be the matrix obtained from the unit $n \times n$ matrix
>   by multiplying the $r$-th row with a number $c$ and adding it to the $s$-th
>   row, $r \neq s$. Let $A$ be an $n \neq n$ matrix. Then $EA$ is obtained from $A$ by
>   multiplying the $r$-th row of $A$ by $c$ and adding it to the $s$-th row of $A$.
>
> Let 
>   $$      E =
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         1 & 0 & 4 & 0\\
>         0  &  1 & 0 & 0\\
>         0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 0& 0& 1 \\
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> Then $E$ is obtained from the unit matrix by adding 4 times the third row
>   to the first row.

I am having a little hard time understanding $r$-th and $s$-th rows.

Is the $r$-th row  here the 3rd row of $n \times n$ unit matrix with $s$-th row being the first row of another $n \times n$ unit matrix? But then wouldn't the $s$-th row occur somewhere between 1st and $n$-th rows?

In general, what are the $r$-th and $s$-th rows in this context?

Thanks.

Comment: $r$ and $s$ are just integers. For example, if $r = 1$, $s = 2$, then $r$-th row just means "first row" (of $E$), and $s$-th row means "second row" (also of $E$).

Comment: Henry Swanson, thank you. I see. I am having a case of variable overload today.